# Debug to Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012

Hello everyone I have Visual Studio Express Windows Phone 2012 installed on my windows 8. I have a windows 7.5 Nokia device. I would like to know how can I debug to device directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the phone connected, and Zune is running (and can see your phone), then you can you the drop down to choose "Device" instead of "Emulator 7.1" (etc.). This will then deploy your debug version of your app to your phone, and run it with the debugger attached, so that you can stop on exceptions/breakpoints/etc. as you would if running on the emulator.